# paintComponent is unstable

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm making a game and although I'm mainly working on the logic first, I have a simple, fast-made draw method:

```
   public class Draw extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//  BufferedImage heroitext;
    Hero hero;
    Vector<Enemy> enemies;
    Vector<Bullet> ammo;
    Vector<Terrain> terrains;

    public Draw() {
//      (int)try {
//          heroitext = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/circulo.png"));
//      } catch (IOException e) {
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
    }

    public void render(Level lvl) {
        hero = lvl.getHero();
        ammo = lvl.getAmmo();
        enemies = lvl.getEnemies();
        terrains = lvl.getTerrains();
        repaint();
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("drawing");

        //draw Hero
        g.drawRect((int)hero.getX(), (int)hero.getY(), hero.getWidth(), hero.getHeight());

        //draw Enemies
        for(int i=0; i<enemies.size(); i++)
        {
            if(!enemies.get(i).isToKill()) g.drawRect((int)enemies.get(i).getX(), (int)enemies.get(i).getY(), enemies.get(i).getWidth(), enemies.get(i).getHeight());
            for(int j=0; j<enemies.get(i).getAmmo().size(); j++)
            {
                g.drawRect((int) enemies.get(i).getAmmo().get(j).getX(), (int)enemies.get(i).getAmmo().get(j).getY(), enemies.get(i).getAmmo().get(j).getWidth(), enemies.get(i).getAmmo().get(j).getHeight());
            }
        }

        //draw Ammo
        for(int i=0; i<ammo.size(); i++)
        {
            g.drawRect((int)ammo.get(i).getX(), (int)ammo.get(i).getY(), ammo.get(i).getWidth(), ammo.get(i).getHeight());
        }

        //draw Terrains
        for(int i=0; i<terrains.size(); i++)
        {
            g.drawRect((int)terrains.get(i).getX(), (int)terrains.get(i).getY(), terrains.get(i).getWidth(), terrains.get(i).getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

And it usually works great, but sometimes, even when I don't change code, some Runs give me a white screen, and with a few println's I found out that although the code reaches repaint() the paintComponent method isn't called at all.

As I said, this only happens sometimes and IT SEEMS unpredictable.

Another thing that happens is when I add around 50000 enemies to the enemy vector, the paintComponent is never called, no matter how many runs I try. From what I researched, some people say it's because java won't bother drawing a panel if another panel is already waiting to be drawn (or something like that) but that doesn't make sense on the first case since I do not change any code.

Can someone explain me what is actually happening and how to properly fix it?

Comment: I think that you're running into a Swing threading issue, that with so many Enemy objects, the JVM is overwhelmed, takes longer to process, and the long-processing code slogs down your Swing event thread. Consider profiling to improve efficiency and also using background threading.

Comment: Consider implementing `draw` methods or something similar in each of your game objects, and using the for each loop syntax `for (Bullet b: ammo) b.draw(g);` to make your code clearer.

Comment: you should know that repaint() only addes a dirty region to the list of things to repaint. the actual painting will be done when the event dispatch thread (EDT) has time to do so. background threading means you prepare as much as you can in another thread (see SwingWorker) and when the work is done you call repaint and paintComponent accesses the prepared stuff.